# How to obtain the ASP.NET Core application name?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I would like do display in the footer of an ASP.NET Core 1.1

> © 2017 MyApplication

```
<p>&copy; 2017 @(ApplicationName)</p>
```

How do I get the application name?

I found [an article](http://michaco.net/blog/EnvironmentVariablesAndConfigurationInASPNETCoreApps) on this subject but it's confusing about `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationName`, because it says do not use `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions`, but does not say what to use instead for the application name...

Comment: Rather than tying it to the assembly name, I think a better solution would be to simply put the exact text you want in the layout file.

Comment: @NateBarbettini The exact text I want is the application name as filled in the project properties.

Answer (score 12):

You could try:

```
@using System.Reflection;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 ....

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2017 - @Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name</p>
    </footer>
</html>
```

I am not sure it is a good way, but it works for me :)

[image]

Comment: what should be the good way, put the application name in resource files?

Comment: for application name only , I prefer to put exact text you want in layout file because application name is not changed frequently. :) btw, developer intuitively understand where it is.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of way to achieve it. Here is how I do in my projects.

I normally have project name different from application name which could have spaces or much longer. So, I Keep the project name and version number in `appsettings.json` file.

**[appsettings.json](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/appsettings.json)**

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "Application": {
      "Name": "ASP.NET Core Active Directory Starter Kit",
      "Version": "2017.07.1"
    }
  }
}
```

**[Startup.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Startup.cs#L56)**

Load setting from  `appsettings.json` file into `AppSettings` POCO. It then automatically register in DI container as `IOptions<AppSettings>`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddOptions();
   services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
}
```

**[AppSettings.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Core/AppSettings.cs)**

***Note***: I have some other settings so that I keep them all together inside AppSettings POCO.

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public Application Application { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

**[Usage (_layout.cshtml)](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml#L59)**

Inject `IOptions<AppSettings>` to View. *You can also inject it to controller if you would like.*

```
@inject IOptions<AppSettings> AppSettings

<footer class="main-footer">
   @AppSettings.Value.Application.Version
   @AppSettings.Value.Application.Name</strong>
</footer>
```

[image]